# How to get items from Personal Microsoft Lists (Not Sharepoint Lists) using Graph REST API?

Tags: rest, list

I'm trying to query my personal Microsoft Lists with Microsoft Graph API without success.
My list is a Microsoft List located in https://lists.live.com/.

My list's URL shown in my browser is [https://lists.live.com/?listId={list_id}_{user_id}](https://lists.live.com/?listId=%7Blist_id%7D_%7Buser_id%7D)

If I log into my personal microsoft account and I use the typical REST API endpoint in my browser address bar and hit ENTER in my keyboard, it yields the expected results in XML:

[https://lists.live.com/personal/{user_id}/_api/Web/Lists(guid'{list_id}')/items](https://lists.live.com/personal/%7Buser_id%7D/_api/Web/Lists(guid%27%7Blist_id%7D%27)/items)

However, whenever I try to query this Microsoft List using Microsoft Graph Explorer, I get this result:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Unable to find target address",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2023-12-31T20:25:24",
        "request-id": {guid_1},
        "client-request-id": {guid_2}
    }
}
```

I've also gotten my Site Id with this endpoint typing it manually in the address bar and gotten results

`https://lists.live.com/personal/{user_id}/_api/site/id`

And then used that site id to try to at least get a pointer that I'm in the right direction in the Explorer
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Unable to find target address"
    }
}
```

But alas I get the above error.

I don't know how to get information from Microsoft Lists for personal accounts (not Sharepoint) using REST API, does anyone know how to do this?

**UPDATE**
I've also found this end-point:
`https://lists.live.com/personal/{user_id}/_api/v2.0/sites/root/lists/{list_id}/items

Happy new year!

Comment: Are you able to access the list from the web https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/{name}/Lists/{list_name} ? If not then I don't see any chance to get items through the Graph API.

Comment: Hi @user2250152 thanks for the reply. No as this is a family 365 office subscription, so no SharePoint involved.  Thanks! Do you know if previous authentication methods would work to get a token for `live.com` and then use that token to use the previous `sharepoint.com` REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you access SharePoint list items via the Graph API like this:

```
GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items
```

There isn’t a way to access personal Microsoft Lists via the Graph API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

If possible try using PnP PowerShell.